# Undefined model fields with `strict: false`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {user: 'mongod'});
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
```

I create a model with one field and strict: false

```
  var Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', mongoose.Schema({
    foo: String
  }, {strict: false}));
```

Then save a model with two fields

```
  Foo.create({foo: "FOO", bar: "BAR"}, function () {
```

Then read it and print it with its fields

```
    Foo.findOne(function (err, f) {
      console.log(f, f.foo, f.bar);
    });

  });
});
```

The output is `{ foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR', _id: 53c249e876be58931f760e70, __v: 0 }`, `'FOO'`, `undefined`. The new element is correctly saved and `console.log` can see `'BAR'`, but I can't. As soon as I add bar to the schema, I can see it too. Is this intended behavior? **How can I reach `bar` without including it in the schema?**

Comment: I know I could define my schema as `{any: {}}`, then create `{any: {foo: "FOO", bar: "BAR"}}` and print `f.any, f.any.foo, f.any.bar`. I would rather not have the extra field though.

Comment: If you use {any: {}} the only problem is that you have to save all the data previously store in the object if you don't want to loose it when you update the object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access fields not defined in your schema with [`get`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get):

```
Foo.findOne(function (err, doc) {
  console.log(doc, doc.foo, doc.get('bar'));
});
```

output:

```
{ _id: 53c28dad3b2464566cf5672d, foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR' } 'FOO' 'BAR'
```

The `bar` field also shows up when logging `doc` as the [`inspect`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-inspect) method of a Mongoose document outputs all fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can access using _doc

example: doc._doc.fieldname